# Cut text and put in another UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uitextview

I need a help

I have this:

```
NSString *txt1 = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac elit in est volutpat laoreet. Sed in turpis id odio molestie commodo et et felis. Praesent at magna mauris, at rutrum lacus. Fusce eu dictum erat. Etiam tellus quam, aliquam a imperdiet non, tempor nec est. Proin quis est lectus. Sed facilisis mauris scelerisque erat auctor ut tempor tellus consectetur. In sed erat non massa tincidunt consectetur. Proin vitae sollicitudin dolor. Morbi euismod hendrerit lorem vitae facilisis. Curabitur suscipit odio in felis eleifend non porttitor dui auctor. Aenean sed libero mauris, vel sagittis neque. Mauris lobortis posuere sapien eget tempus. Sed scelerisque viverra scelerisque. Proin pharetra, tortor in adipiscing egestas, ante massa ultrices tellus, vitae molestie enim ante id diam. Aenean auctor mi a massa aliquet et facilisis nisi dignissim. Proin mauris turpis, fringilla et viverra ut, porta ac massa. Nulla adipiscing tincidunt metus, eget faucibus enim luctus interdum. Suspendisse tortor nibh, elementum ut dictum ac, ultricies quis nulla. Donec dictum, felis ac fermentum facilisis, augue dui mattis orci, ac feugiat mauris ante sit amet ligula. Nullam in dolor velit, non consectetur nisl. Nunc nec risus ante. Maecenas sapien dolor, faucibus a condimentum nec, luctus ut nulla. Donec feugiat ullamcorper risus. Quisque consequat pharetra velit, nec venenatis nibh pretium vitae. Mauris tempor tincidunt sagittis.";

NSString *txt2 = @"Quisque nec dui mauris, eget vestibulum arcu. Duis sed lacus lectus. Proin fermentum sapien eer conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos Quisque nec dui mauris, eget vestibulum arcu. Duis sed lacus lectus. Proin fermentum sapien eer conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos Quisque nec dui mauris, eget vestibulum arcu. Duis sed lacus lectus.";

NSString *txt3 = @"Suspendisse id arcu malesuada sem varius bibendum eu sit amet diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur quis tortor tristique nibh hendrerit luctus. Nullam nec augue quis libero malesuada blandit. Suspendisse et tellus dolor, eleifend condimentum augue. Aenean interdum, lorem a tincidunt laoreet, nisi neque dictum mi, ac laoreet lacus sem iaculis lorem. Cras ullamcorper mauris et quam euismod ac semper libero volutpat. Etiam massa risus, lobortis facilisis hendrerit eu, blandit sit amet nisi. Quisque sit amet nunc vel nunc aliquet dignissim in eget est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec varius suscipit dolor nec placerat. Ut eu dui vel nisl pretium sagittis nec quis risus. Suspendisse ut arcu enim, sit amet posuere libero. In dui magna, viverra id dictum eget, ornare et erat. Phasellus sit amet mi a magna iaculis scelerisque id eget turpis. Nam vitae mauris nunc. Curabitur erat ligula, consequat sit amet blandit ut, luctus in dui. Pellentesque non dignissim neque. Mauris mollis, lorem a aliquam faucibus, mi libero dignissim nisi, non luctus tortor mi vel magna. Vestibulum pellentesque, quam id consectetur iaculis, ipsum nibh aliquam nisi, eget tempor metus ipsum at neque. Vivamus elit urna, vestibulum varius pulvinar sit amet, vehicula quis ligula. Sed semper urna a erat pretium ut semper sem euismod.";



NSArray *textos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:txt1,txt2,txt3,nil];

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024)];

scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

[scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite];

int numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * 768;
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin,0,768,1024)];
    [textView setText:[textos objectAtIndex:i]];

    CGRect frameText = textView.frame;
    frameText.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
    textView.frame = frameText;



    [scrollView addSubview:textView];
    [textView release];
}


scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfViews * 768, 1024);


[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

And show a UIScrollView with pages, but the first text is biggest then 1024 pixels of the height.
how can I cut the text and put leftovers in another page with txt2?

Thanks

Comment: I scrolled the whole day on my iPhone trying to read this post completely..., I finally gave up :) - ps look at NSString substringWithRange

Comment: Is this text dynemic or static ?

Comment: In this example is a static text, but I'm doing with a dynamic text. And I get this dynamic text from xml...

Comment: Dynamic... I get this text from XML!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is any inbuilt functionality to do this but you can try this thing

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
NSArray *arrTxt1 = [txt1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableString *restOFStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *initialStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
BOOL gotStr = NO;
for (NSString *tStr in arrTxt1) {
    if (gotStr) {
        [initialStr appendString:tStr];
        CGSize size = [initialStr sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(768, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        if(size.height > 1024){
            // Displayed in first page
            [initialStr deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(initialStr.length-tStr.length, tStr.length)];
            //Add tStr to restOfStr
            [restOFStr appendString:tStr];
            gotStr = YES;
        }
        else {
            [initialStr appendString:@" "];
        }
    }
    else {
        //Collect the rest of string
        [restOFStr appendString:tStr];
    }
}
```

**Edit**

The logic here I'm using is to get the string that fits in the 768x1024 UITextView.
For that I divided your string into components separated by space i.e. if your string is `"Hello how are you?"`
Then the array will have

```
arrTxt1[0]---->Hello
arrTxt1[1]---->how
arrTxt1[2]---->are
arrTxt1[3]---->you?
```

Then I'm calculating the size and checking if height is less than 1024 then I append the string and where it exceeds 1024 I stop appending.
At last you have `initialStr` which will fit in 768x1024 and `restOFStr` the leftover string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... I am new to iOS development

Comment: @user1887732 I have edited hope you understand. If you don't then please read the documentation of each method I have used and then have some hit and trial and understand.

Comment: Yes, I understood! I did with text, now I'm going to try to put image between text!